# Ford Mondeo mk3 Radio 6006e ISO adaptor

Tags: ford, audio, mondeo, adapt

I need to replace a radio-cd 6006e and I need the ISO adaptor. I don't know what is it or where to find that information.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did it with the following adaptor.
[image]

There are different series with different connectors, the one that pointed @CharlieRB was for an other one.
This fits on 6006 and 6000 eon radios but... losing the steering wheel control.

If you want to continue using it, you need an adaptor interface wich cost more than a cheap radio (avoid poor quality interfaces, they can produce extrage behaviour in the car electrical system).

Take note that the orange and black sockets are connected into the green radio socket, one on top of the other. The radio antenna have their adaptor too.

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

Suppliers vary depending the part of the world you live in. What you are looking for is a wire harness adapter that will allow you to connect your aftermarket radio to the factory wire harness. It essentially plugs in where you unplugged from the radio.

Do an Internet search for "ford mondeo iso adapter". It will look something like this.

[image]

Some are complete, while some require you to splice the wires from your new radio harness to this adapter.